# URL will update url page will not render with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following App component:

```
const { store, persistor } = storeFunc()

// manually pass into <Router history={history}>
// const history = createBrowserHistory();

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <BlockScroll>
              <Header />
              <DisplayModals />
                <div className="page" ref={(page) => this.page = page}>
                  <Switch>
                    {/* // KITCHEN ROUTES */}
                    <Route component={About} exact path="/about/" />
                    <Route component={GTC} exact path="/agb/" />
                    <Route component={GdprDetail} exact path="/gdpr/" />
                    <Route component={OrderRequestSuccess} exact path="/services/order-request-success/" />
                    {/* // USER ROUTES */}
                    <Route component={ResendActivation} exact path="/resend-activation/" />
                    <Route component={requireAuth(Account)} exact path="/account/" />
                    <Route component={requireAuth(AccountManagement)} exact path="/account-management/" />
                    <Route component={ActivateUserLanding} exact path="/activate-user/:uidb64/:token/" />
                    <Route component={ResetPasswordForm} exact path="/reset-password/:uidb64/:token/" />
                    <Route component={ActivateUser} exact path="/activate-user" />
                    <Route component={Registration} exact path="/registration" />
                    <Route component={requireAuth(KitschoenIndex)} exact path="/kitchen-index" />
                    {/* // STATIC ROUTES */}
                    <Route component={ContactForm} exact path="/contact/" />
                    <Route component={IndexView} exact path="/" />
                  </Switch>
                </div>
              <Footer />
            </BlockScroll>
          </BrowserRouter>
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

This yields (for some reason) to weird behaviour. When I try to follow a link component from a component within the Switch, the url will update but the page will not re-render or refresh to the new page. Let's say the component for the `/about/` page is displayed and contains a link to `/agb/` the url will say `www.example.com/agb/` but I will sill be on the about page. If I refresh manually I am at the `/agb/` page.

The weird part is, that the Header Component seems to work just fine. If I click a `Link` from the `Header` everything works. I also tried using just a `Router` component and inserting the history manually with the same result.

**UPDATE**
So, I deleted react-router and react-router-dom and reinstalled it. After this it worked again ...

```
npm uninstall --save react-router
npm uninstall --save react-router-dom
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the components inside **withRouter**.

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
...
...
...
export default withRouter(App);
```

Comment: hey - maybe I should have specified it a little more ... I am using the Link component to link between pages. withRouter injects history to the props. However ... with or without withRouter ... it does not work.